# How to set windowSoftInputMode programmatically on different screens in react-native?

Tags: react-native

In my react-native app, I need different screen behaviour on different screens when keyboard pops up.
In some screens i need the screen to move up, and in some screens i do not want to change the screen position etc.

Individual behaviours can be achieved by setting values of `android:windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustNothing` or `adjustResize` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

But setting these values in the manifest file changes the behaviour for all the screens.

Is there a way to change it programmatically within different screens ?

In android code it looks [achievable using a getWindow() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138330/is-there-any-way-to-change-androidwindowsoftinputmode-value-from-java-class). How to do it in react-native ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this component [react-native-android-keyboard-adjust](https://github.com/zubricky/react-native-android-keyboard-adjust)

When the component in which you don't want to move up views mounts, set `AndroidKeyboardAdjust.setAdjustPan()` and when that component unmount reset it to `AndroidKeyboardAdjust.setAdjustResize()` or whatever option that suits your criteria

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62695159) answer

Answer (score 1):

try use ScrollView instead of View then wrap it on KeyboardAvoidingView

Comment: ScrollView also pushes the view Up. on Some screens i do not want any screen change (i want lower part of the screen to get hidden when keyboard pops up, and upper part, which is a map, should not move at all, its possible with "adjustNothing" value, but it should be dynamically set on this screen only)

Answer (score 0):

I needed a view that that did not adjust the screen when the keyboard appeared on android so I created a component that turns off the screen adjust feature and then returns it adjustResize when the component unmounts. It uses 'rn-android-keyboard-adjust' which is based on 'react-native-android-keyboard-adjust'.

```
import { setAdjustResize, setAdjustNothing } from 'rn-android-keyboard-adjust'

function Login() {
  return (
    <KeyboardAdjustNothingView style={...} >
      <Input />
      <Input />
    </KeyboardAdjustNothingView>
  )
}

function KeyboardAdjustNothingView(props:ViewProps) {

  useEffect(() => {
    setAdjustNothing()
    return () => {
      setAdjustResize()
    }
  }, [])

  return <View {...props } />
}
```